# Sending Form Data from Angular 6 to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angular

config.service.ts file ->

```
 constructor (private http:Http){
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });    
        this.API_BASE_URL='http://localhost/confalerts/api/savetodb.php';

     }

saveConference(data){
     return this.http.post(this.API_BASE_URL,data,this.options).map((res)=>res.json(),(err)=>err);
 }
```

Service call in component.ts ->

```
  let data=this.newconfForm.value;
      let pair={action_type:"saveconference"};
      data={...data,...pair};   
        this.configSvc.saveConference(data).subscribe((jsondata)=>{
          console.log('successfully called');
      },(err)=>{

      });
```

PHP File ->

```
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$postData=json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
print_r($postData);`
```

My problem is-> PHP file throws the NOTICE:

> Notice:  Undefined index: Formdata in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\confalerts\api\savetodb.php on line **8**

```
$postData=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

is an easy hack but i'll be uploading files in this form as well so I dont wish to use the `php://input` file.

What could be a possible solution?
I tried appending headers, but `header.append()` is apparently not a supported function.

Comment: Change your Angular Header also to `'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'` and then do a `print_r($_POST)` and take a look at whats coming in.

Comment: I am a beginner, what will that become? let headers = new Headers({  'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' });   -> this is giving an error, you gotta share exact syntax please

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Your code doesn't include "Formdata" anywhere, so this is not what's causing the error. Regardless, this is a duplicate.

Comment: you have posted your code, replace your formdata header: `let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' })`

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull , your idea worked, my data is going to the PHP file now, but it is filled with underscores.. Array([{ _"title":_"hello" }]) something like this, should i ask a new question, or something...

Comment: Edit your post with a example response, then i can help you.